# Good capture with pcap_next_ex(), but different Ethernet Header sizes. 14 with Ubuntu, 4 with FreeBSD

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, packet, libpcap

I have a running application that needed to execute properly on both my local platform, running Ubuntu 18.4, and recompiled, run on a FreeBSD platform.

I encountered a problem with the packets because the Ethernet header was 10 bytes shorter on the FreeBSD platform

I have accommodated the difference in software following the receipt of the packet by looking into the packet for data from the ICMP Header that is always present in my data.  Knowing the offset to that data informs the decision about the header size.

Once I know the size of the Ethernet header, I strip it off, and what remains is consistent across devices.

But, I'm bugged that there is a difference that I cannot understand.  Can anyone point me to documentation describing the reason why the difference of 4 or 14 bytes?

I have explored the web looking for an explanation, but found nothing that would justify the difference.  Even FreeBSD 'Ethernet.h' shows 14 bytes.

```
#define ETHER_HDR_LEN (ETHER_ADDR_LEN*2 + ETHER_TYPE_LEN) where that is (6*2)+2 equals 14
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are capturing on the loopback interface (`lo` on Linux, `lo0` on FreeBSD), there is no guarantee that the packets will *have* an Ethernet header.  They do on Linux, but they have a different header on FreeBSD (and NetBSD and OpenBSD and DragonFly BSD and macOS); that header is 4 bytes long.

Once you've opened an interface for capturing, you ***MUST*** call `pcap_datalink()` on the `pcap_t`; that tells you what the headers are.  You must ***NOT*** assume an Ethernet header.

See [this list of link-layer header types](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for descriptions of the link-layer header types you might see. `pcap_datalink()` returns a DLT_ value, not a LINKTYPE_ value, so compare its result against the DLT_ values from that page.